# DLL injection CreateRemoteThread not working on some clients (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, code-injection

I created a launcher in .NET which starts a singleplayer game and injects a DLL into it.
It works on my own machine and several others, yet on some people's computers it seems to fail mysteriously. I have no idea what the reason could probably be and can't directly debug it either since it's working for me. Maybe some of you ran into the same problem or have an idea what could be wrong.

This is the injection code of the launcher (.NET Framework 4.5.2, target platform: Any CPU [prefer 32bit]):

```
    static void StartProcess()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetFullPath("..");
        psi.EnvironmentVariables.Add("GUCProject", projectName);
        psi.FileName = Path.GetFullPath("..\\Gothic2.exe");
        Process process = Process.Start(psi);

        string dllPath = Path.GetFullPath("UntoldChapters\\" + projectName + "\\NetInject.dll");

        //dll injection
        if (LoadLibary(process, dllPath) == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum AllocationType
    {
        Commit = 0x1000,
        Reserve = 0x2000,
        Decommit = 0x4000,
        Release = 0x8000,
        Reset = 0x80000,
        Physical = 0x400000,
        TopDown = 0x100000,
        WriteWatch = 0x200000,
        LargePages = 0x20000000
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MemoryProtection : uint
    {
        Execute = 0x10,
        ExecuteRead = 0x20,
        ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
        ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
        NoAccess = 0x01,
        ReadOnly = 0x02,
        ReadWrite = 0x04,
        WriteCopy = 0x08,
        GuardModifierflag = 0x100,
        NoCacheModifierflag = 0x200,
        WriteCombineModifierflag = 0x400
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, UInt32 nSize, out UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, out uint lpThreadId);

    public static IntPtr LoadLibary(Process process, String dll)
    {
        if (process == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dll))
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        byte[] dllb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dll);
        if (dllb == null || dllb.Length == 0)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        //Alloc
        uint len = (uint)dllb.Length + 1;
        IntPtr dllbPtr = VirtualAllocEx(process.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, len, AllocationType.Reserve | AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
        if (dllbPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        }

        //Write dll name
        uint tmp = 0;
        bool b = WriteProcessMemory(process.Handle, dllbPtr, dllb, (uint)dllb.Length, out tmp);
        if (!b)
        {
            throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        }

        IntPtr moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
        if (moduleHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        }

        IntPtr loadlib = GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, "LoadLibraryA");
        if (loadlib == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        }

        return CreateRemoteThread(process.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadlib, dllbPtr, 0, out tmp);
    }
```

There are no error messages shown / exceptions thrown to the people for which it doesn't work, all the pointers, handles and paths seem fine, yet the DLLMain of the injected 'NetInject.dll' is not called.

(target platform Windows 8.1, toolset VS2015 (v140), Multibyte character set, no CLR-support)

```
int WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    // this is just the testing code for the people for which it doesn't work. It doesn't even get till here.
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Injected!", L"Error!", MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
    return true;
}
```

- The Launcher is always started with administatory rights.
- The OS seems not to be the problem since it's working and failing for some
  people with the same OS. (Working on Win8.1 64Bit, Win7 Professional
  64Bit, Win7 Enterprise 64Bit, Win7 Home Premium 64Bit)
  (Not working on Win7 Professional 64Bit, Win 10 64Bit)
- It's also not working for them with turned off Anti-Virus (anyways I have the same Anti-Virus as one of the problematic testers).
- Compiled in Release mode.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is only a guess, but try doing WaitForInputIdle() after Process.Start.

Comment: Tried it, hasn't changed anything. Thank you though.

Answer (score -1):

See [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx). In "General Best Practices" it says "You should never" ... "Call functions in User32.dll or Gdi32.dll" from DllMain. MessageBox is in User32.dll. Even if you are using MessageBox as a test, you need to ensure you are complying with the General Best Practices.

Yes, I know that the General Best Practices are quite limiting. I was surprised about this when I first found it.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. It doesn't solve the problem though. :p

Comment: Tried it with an ofstream instead of a MessageBox, it didn't work. :(

Comment: We cannot be sure that ofstream works in a DllMain. Get WinDbg from [Download the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) and WinDbg – Windows 10 Hardware Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365). You can use [OutputDebugStgring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) and WinDbg will get the messages.

Comment: I really appreciate your dedication to help and will have a look at the WDK. Yet I probably already found the source of error, which is not (directly) within the code posted but simply some missing/wrong redistributable libraries. Apparently both "msvcp140.dll" and "vcruntime140.dll" needed to be provided as their 32Bit version, which was not the case for one of the testers (the started process is a 32Bit application). (I will wait for the feedback of another tester and then post an 'official' answer if it succeeded.)

Comment: [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) can be used with **any** Windows debugger. Visual Studio will display the string in its *Output* pane. No need to download and install WinDbg.

Comment: @IInspectable, note that the program is injecting a DLL into another process. So yes it would be possible to do something such as create a process that executes VS that debugs the other process **instead of** executing the other process directly, but one disadvantage is that VS takes time to start. Use of WinDbg makes many things easier and does not require a special version of the program that does the injecting. VS can debug only one process at a time whereas WinDbg can be used for multiple processes.

Comment: If you really want a lightweight tool to display output from `OutputDebugString`, go with [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx). Besides, Visual Studio 2015 can be configured to debug child processes. There are valid reasons to use WinDbg. This is not one of them.

Comment: This is becoming a discussion and we are not supposed to have discussions. Sure, "DebugView" looks good but there is no reason to say "This is not one of them". Just suggesting DebugView is good but you keep trying to make me wrong. Go ahead and have the final words on this, we need to avoid a discussion.

Comment: Disclaimer: This is not a discussion. *"VS can debug only one process at a time."* - [Uhm, no, that's not correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919165.aspx).

Comment: See [Debug Multiple Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919165.aspx). In "Switch between processes" it says "only one process is active in the debugger at any given time". So we are both right. Instead of telling me what the person **can't** do you should be telling them what they **can** do.